# Python put string into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to convert a string into a dictionary. I saved this dictionary previously in a text file.

The problem is now, that I am not sure, how the structure of the keys are. The values are generated with Counter(dictionaryName). The dictionary is really large, so I cannot check every key to see how it would be possible.

The keys can contain simple quotes like ', double quotes ", commas and maybe other characters. So is there any possibility to convert it back into a dictionary?

For example this is stored in the file:

```
Counter({'element0':512, "'4,5'element1":50, '4:55foobar':23,...})
```

I found previous solutions with for example json, but I have problems with the double quotes and I cannot simply split for the commas.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, and indeed, what you are even working with exactly... What, **exactly** is stored in a file? How did you "save the dictionary"? Did you literally just write the string representation to a file?That would be your first mistake - you should have used one of the many available serialization formats.

Comment: so you have the dictionary in text form ? and you want to convert it into dictionary?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi yes I stored it in a text file. It took a lot of hours to get the dictionary, so I wanted to save it in a file. But I didn't expect, that it would contain double quotes etc.

Comment: Again, **that is your first problem**. You should have considered *beforehand* how you were going to serialize your data. Python has a `pickle` module that would have made this trivial. Just use `eval` and then *use `pickle`* to properly serialize your object.

Comment: If it is *your data* and you used something like `repr` to write that to the file, just use `eval` to reverse the process. As others have said, it is better to fix the problem in how the file was created as use `cPickle` to store the data.

Comment: @dawg `cPickle`? dawg, what is this, 1999? It's just `pickle` now. Python 3k came and went over a *decade* ago ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trust the source, load `from collections import Counter` and `eval()` the string

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
>> from collections import Counter
>> line = '''Counter({'element0':512, "'4,5'element1":50, '4:55foobar':23})'''
>> D = eval(line)
>> D
 Counter({"'4,5'element1": 50, '4:55foobar': 23, 'element0': 512})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `Counter(` and `)` parts, then parse the rest with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as long as it only involves basic Python data types:

```
import ast

def parse_Counter_string(s):
    s = s.strip()
    if not (s.startswith('Counter(') and s.endswith(')')):
        raise ValueError('String does not match expected format')
    # Counter( is 8 characters
    # 12345678
    s = s[8:-1]
    return Counter(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

In the future, I recommend picking a different way to serialize your data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `demjson` library for doing this, you can have the text directly in your program

```
import demjson

counter = demjson.decode("enter your text here")
```

if it is in the file ,you can do the following steps :

```
WD = dirname(realpath(__file__))
file = open(WD, "filename"), "r")
counter = demjson.decode(file.read())
file.close()
```